# Get path of resource in .Jar to use in Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, path

My controller in Spring Boot copy the directory /resources/templates to generate a new Web Site, in this folder there are all the files i need, html, js, css ext ext.
Running from IDE all work, example with path `target/classes/templates` , but in the moment i created the package in .jar dont work anymore. This is because the path i used is wrong, not access to the folder /templates/, i tried many things, my last tried is this, but dont work.

```
String templatePath="";
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
        Resource resource = null;
        try {
            resource = resolver.getResource("classpath:/templates/");
            templatePath = resource.getURL().getPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I need the path in string, to pass to this function ...

```
templateServices.copyDirectory(templatePath, relativePath);

public void copyDirectory(String pathSrc, String pathDest) {
        File srcDir = new File(pathSrc);
        File destDir = new File(pathDest);
        try {
            System.out.println("Directory Created");
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
            System.out.println("Template Copied");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The error in runtime is this.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source 'file:\C:\Users\asdasdasd\Desktop\newFolder\asd.jar!\BOOT-INF\classes!\templates' does not exist
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.checkFileRequirements(FileUtils.java:
1383)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1346)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1246)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1215)
        at asd.transfer.Services.TemplateServices.copyDirectory(TemplateSer
vices.java:27)
        at asd.transfer.Controller.FileController.uploadFiles(FileControlle
r.java:96)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvok
e(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeF
orRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocabl
eHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingH
andlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapt
er.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(Dispatch
erServlet.java:1039)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(Dispatche
rServlet.java:942)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(Frame
workServlet.java:1005)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServ
let.java:908)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:882)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterIntern
al(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerR
equestFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(Appl
icationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationF
ilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperV
alve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextV
alve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java
:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLig
ht.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(Abstract
Protocol.java:853)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpo
int.java:1587)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBas
e.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskTh
read.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You can directly get the reference to the file. 

Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/test.properties");
File file = resource.getFile();

Comment: I dont need this. I need the path to use in my function, to copy the directory from jar to out.

Answer (score 1):

But your resource **IS NOT A FILE** so any attempt to treat it as one is doomed to fail. For example, @Shuki's comment doesn't work if the resource isn't a file (and in your example, it isn't: It's an entry in a jar file).

The solution is to take whatever code demands a file and fix it. You should never demand a file; an inputstream or alternatively a URL (from which you can get an inputstream) is what your code should need, and nothing more. I don't know what package `asd.transfer` is nor who wrote it, but they need to fix it / you should not use it.

Alternatively, if you must, then you can't really use the classpath here, or you're forced to distribute this bit of your code not as a jar file; you'd have to unpack it before your code works. Which is not idiomatic java and generally not worth the trouble.

`YourClassName.class.getResource("somefile.txt")` gets you a URI you can use; `YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("somefile.txt")` gets you an inputstream to read. That's what you should write your code for; not files.

Comment: I have in /resources/ the folder public and the folder templates, i use the folder templates to create other web site, so i need to access in this folder, because there are the files to copy, css, js, html ext ext, all worked, but in the moment i create the jar, and the folder templates is in this jar, the path a gave before is wrong, i need to take the path of the folder in jar, how can i do?

Comment: @D.Corra as I said: It is not possible.